# How to connect 2 VMware instance running on same Linux host machine via emulated ethernet cable (accessible via mac address)?

Tags: ethernet, vmware, virtualbox-networking

I have a host machine running Linux (ubuntu-18.04). There I have 2 VMware instances configured and the network is configured via NAT. I can ping from VM1 to VM2 (and vice-versa) via their local IPs but for my current need, I want them to be connected via ethernet cable for the DPDK test environment so that one machine can find another by direct mac address(layer 2 protocol, without IP stack). How to do that in an easy and efficient way and test that it is working (via arping probably, not sure) correctly?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. How can two VMs inside a single host using an Ethernet cable? Are you talking about a virtual cable?

Comment: its about emulating, let me update the title

Comment: What IP addresses are getting assigned to the 2 VMs? They should be in the same subnet to communicate with each other.